# Corollary of Lebesgue's DCT from Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Hello! After attentive reading of this theorem I have some questions:

$1)$ If $E=\{x\in S: \varphi(x)<\infty\}$ then what is $E^c$? I know that it's the complement of set $E$, i.e. $E^c=\{x\in S: \varphi(x)=\infty\}$. Am I right?

$2)$ How rigorously show that $\mu(E^c)=0$? I couldn't show this by myself.

$3)$ After applying Theorem 1.34 we get $(3)$ with $E$ in place of $X$. Since $\mu(E^c)=0$ we get $(3)$ with $S$ in place of $X$. But $\int \limits_{X}fd\mu$ does not make sense since $f$ is defined only on $S$ and we have no information about $f$ on $X-S$.

Any comment\answer would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Suppose that $\mu(E^c)>0$ and let $\alpha=\int\limits_{S}\varphi d\mu<\infty$. Let $s$ be the simple function $0\leqslant s \leqslant \varphi$ taking value $\frac{\alpha+1}{\mu(E^c)}$. Then by definition of $\int\limits_{S}\varphi d\mu$ we have the following inequalities: $$\alpha=\int\limits_{S}\varphi d\mu\geqslant \int\limits_{E^c}\varphi d\mu \geqslant \int\limits_{E^c}s d\mu=\dfrac{\alpha+1}{\mu(E^c)}\cdot \mu(E^c)=\alpha+1$$ but it's a contradiction since $\alpha \geqslant 0$.

Comment: 1. No. $E^c =S^c\cup\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}$.

Comment: That makes more sense! Thank you. What did you think about my edit?

Comment: @JohnDawkins, In my edit i showed that $\{x\in S: \varphi(x)=\infty\}$ has zero measure then by sud-additivity of measure $\mu(E^c)\leqslant \mu(S^c)+\mu(\{x\in S: \varphi(x)=\infty\})=0$.

Comment: Also how to understand $\int \limits_{X}f_1d\mu$ because $f_1$ is defined only on S_1 and not defined on $S_1^c$ which has zero measure.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. If $\mu(E^c)>0$, then $$\int\varphi\geq\int_{E^c}\varphi=\infty.$$
3. As mentioned in the book, in the line before $(4)$, $\mu(S^c)=0$.

Comment: 2. I am also made the same inequality but I couldn't show that $\int \limits_{E^c}\varphi d\mu=\infty$ rigorously.

Comment: On $E^c$, you have that $\varphi$ is a simple function, so $\int_{E^c}\varphi=\infty\times\mu(E^c)=\infty$.

Comment: Dear Martin. But in Rudin's book simple function takes only finite values.

Comment: Yes, but the simple functions defined on $E^c$ take infinite value, as you noted in the (1) of your question. When you evaluate the integral, if $\mu(E^c)$ were positive, you would get the equalities made in Martins first comment

Comment: @RFZ: if that's the case, then integration makes no sense for functions that take $\infty$ as a value. I doubt that's the setup in Rudin.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, I make an edit in my post. Can you take a look at my approach?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Dear Martin! May I ask you one qiestion? I thought about it for some time and I'm sure that $E^c=S^c\cup \{x\in S: \varphi(x)=\infty\}$ (the same answer was offered by John Dawkins above). and it's easy to show that $\mu(E^c)=0$. But even if $\mu(E^c)=0$ why $\int \limits_{E^c}f_jd\mu$ is zero? After all $f_j$ is not defined at whole $E^c$. It turns out how we can talk about Lebesgue integral of function on a set where function is not defined?

Comment: Will you answer to my question?